# How can I execute existing sqoop job using java?

Tags: hadoop2, sqoop

Here I am doing Incremental import using Java. But I am not getting how to use already existing job.

I mean

```
sqoop job --create moviesJob1 -- import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb --username root -P --table movies --m 1 --target-dir /movies --incremental append --check-column movieId --last-val 0



 SqoopOptions options  = new SqoopOptions();
            options.setJobName(tableDTO.getTableName()+"Job");
            options.setDriverClassName(driver);
            options.setHadoopHome(HADOOP_HOME);
            options.setConnectString(MYSQL_CONNECTION_STRING);
            options.setUsername(USERNAME);
            options.setPassword(PASSWORD);
            options.setTableName(tableDTO.getTableName());
            options.setNumMappers(Integer.parseInt(tableDTO.getNoOfMappers()));
            options.setTargetDir(HDFS_DIRECTORY_PATH+"/"+tableDTO.getTableName());
            options.setFieldsTerminatedBy('|');
            options.setAppendMode(true);
            options.setIncrementalMode(IncrementalMode.AppendRows);
            options.setIncrementalLastValue("0");
```

I have written code for this,
now I have to execute:

```
sqoop job --exec moviesJob1
```

To execute this:

```
 options.getJobName(); // getting JobName but not finding method to run job
```

Can anyone give suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
new ExportTool().run(options);
```

or:

```
new com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool().run(options);
```